# How do I close and open my sidebar onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, slider

Whenever I use it, the side bar is always open even when I didn’t click the button to do so.  In other words, whenever I refresh my browser, the side bar is already opened.  I want it to be closed, only when I click the button should the side bar open up.

But I want it to open and close on command.  I tried playing around with the supported props but still no luck :(.

I'm using this btw https://github.com/balloob/react-sidebar#installation

Here's my `App.js` file:

```
import React from "react";
import Sidebar from "react-sidebar";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sidebarOpen: true
        };
        this.onSetSidebarOpen = this.onSetSidebarOpen.bind(this);
    }

    onSetSidebarOpen(open) {
        this.setState({ sidebarOpen: open });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Sidebar
                sidebar={<div><b>Sidebar content</b><b>Sidebar content</b><b>Sidebar content</b><b>Sidebar content</b><b>Sidebar content</b><b>Sidebar content</b><b>Sidebar content</b><b>Sidebar content</b></div>}
                open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
                onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
                styles={{ sidebar: { background: "white" } }}
            >
                <button onClick={() => this.onSetSidebarOpen(true)}>
                    Open sidebar
                </button>
            </Sidebar>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you want it to start as closed, then initial the value to false ..

```
    this.state = {
        sidebarOpen: false
    };
```

Secondly, if you want it to open and close , set onClick normally -> `onClick={this.onSetSidebarOpen}` :

```
onSetSidebarOpen() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ sidebarOpen: !prevState.sidebarOpen }));
}
```

In general - of course it stays open, you set the value to true by default, and it stays true for ever.

Comment: I truly feel like an idiot... I was making methods, calling functions, re-writing everything, doing all sorts of crazy stuff.  I've figured out way more trivial things than this issue.  Thank you, sagi and apologies for wasting your time.